# Weird struct packing

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment, bit-fields, packing

While working on some frames structure, I came across a  weird behavior.
I quickly tested it in and independent sample code with following:

```
struct non_alligned_struct
{
    uint8_t  flag;

    // start of uint32 bit fields
    uint32_t a:2;
    uint32_t b:2;
    uint32_t c:1;
    uint32_t d:1;
    uint32_t e:1;
    uint32_t f:1;
    uint32_t g:3;
    uint32_t h:1;
    uint32_t i:1;
    uint32_t j:3;
    uint32_t k:3;
    uint32_t l:1;
    uint32_t m:1;
    uint32_t n:1;
    uint32_t o:1;
    uint32_t p:3;
    uint32_t q:2;
    uint32_t r:1;
    uint32_t s:1;
    uint32_t t:2;
    //4 bytes ends here

    // shouldn't this start at 5th byte ??
    uint16_t u;

    uint16_t v:13;
    uint16_t w:3;

    uint16_t x;

    uint16_t y:13;
    uint16_t z:3;
};

int main()
{
    struct non_alligned_struct obj1;
    void *ptr1 = &obj1;
    void *ptr2 = &(obj1.u);
    printf("ptr1: %p, ptr2: %p, ptr2 - ptr1: %d\n", ptr1, ptr2, ptr2 - ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
ptr1: 0x7fff3216a620, ptr2: 0x7fff3216a626, ptr2 - ptr1: 6

Question: Why ptr2 - ptr1 should be 6. As per my calculation it should have been 5. Also the Structure is 13 bytes, so it gets 4 bytes aligned and the padding is done at weird way. I verified by giving random values to member variables and I observe that padding is done at following **bold locations**

00000000: 01 22 31 10 67 **00** fe ff 86 01 fe ff 86 01 **00 00**

Comment: ptr2-ptr1 definitely equals 6...

Comment: In MSVC if I enclose the `struct` with `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)` it gives your expected result `5`, otherwise `8`. I had to change the `void*` pointers to `char*` because pointer arithmetic on `void*` types is implementation defined.

Comment: Constraint violation doing arithmetic on `void*`s. Your compiler was obligated to issue a diagnostic for this error.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment of bit fields is implementation-defined. Your implementation appears to use 1 or (possibly 2)-byte alignment for the `uint32_t` field. As a result, `flag` occupies byte 0, and the bit field occupies bytes 1..4 or 2..5. In the former case, `u` defaults to 2-byte alignment which puts it at bytes 6..7, and in the latter case, 6..7 is already the next available slot.

Comment: Fromt the bold hex dump in the OP, I'd say that the bit-field is 1-byte aligned, and the `u` field is 2-byte aligned, as expected for a `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Why ptr2 - ptr1 should be 6. As per my calculation it should have been 5.

C allows implementations to insert padding between and after struct elements in any amount and any arrangement they choose.  Additionally, it does not specify how bit fields are allocated to addressible storage units, nor what size the addressible storage units to which they are assigned may be.  In particular, the declared type of a bitfield says nothing about that as far as the standard is concerned.

In the end, therefore, you can compute how many bits are required to represent the structure members before `u`, but you *cannot* compute what the offset of `u` should be based only on the declaration of the containing structure.

In practice, it's not surprising to see `u` positioned at an even offset from the beginning of the structure.  It follows that there is some padding in the struct representation, but exactly where that padding is is difficult to ascertain, since you cannot take compute address of a bitfield.